# NirCMD keypress и кнопка Windows

Tags: windows, keypress

Почему-то не получается раскрыть все окна с помощью комбинации клавиш через средства NirCMD .
Есть 5 сгруппированных окон на первом месте, значит их комбинации:

```
win+1 для 1 окна
Win+1+1 для 2 окна
Win+1+1+1 для 3 окна
Win+1+1+1+1 для 4 окна
Win+1+1+1+1+1 для 5 окна
```

Код

```
cd /D D:\Downloads\nircmd-x64
::Комбинации для вызова окон
SET Win_1=1
SET Win_2=1 1
SET Win_3=1 1 1
SET Win_4=1 1 1 1
SET Win_5=1 1 1 1 1

set COUNTER=1
SET Win_Count=0
goto loop

:loop
if %COUNTER%==6 goto end
if %COUNTER%==5 (
    set COUNTER=6
    set Win_Count=%Win_5%
    )
if %COUNTER%==4 (
    set COUNTER=5
    set Win_Count=%Win_4%
    )
if %COUNTER%==3 (
    set COUNTER=4
    set Win_Count=%Win_3%
    )
if %COUNTER%==2 (
    set COUNTER=3
    set Win_Count=%Win_2%
    )
if %COUNTER%==1 (
    set COUNTER=2
    set Win_Count=%Win_1%
    )

::Вызов окна
nircmd sendkey rwin down
nircmd wait 2000
nircmdc sendkey %Win_Count% press
nircmd wait 2000
nircmd sendkey rwin up
nircmd wait 2000

goto loop

:end
```

После первого открытия окна скриптом, второе и последующее не открывается и почему-то, визуально на экране, нажимается один раз win с открытием боковой панели windows.

Answer (score 0):

Мда...

```
nircmd sendkeypress %Win_Count%
```

нужно было